# Create and use floating point texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, floating-point, textures

I am trying to create floating point texture in OpenGL.
I have 4 vertexes (2 polygons) forming square:

```
                  -------
                  |\    |
                  |  \  |
                  |    \|
                  -------
```

Now I want to create texture with float values, each value of texture to represent basic color intensity of each pixel.

I want to calculate pixel color in fragment shader like this:

```
color = texture2D(texture, coordinates).r * vec4(0.4, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0);
```

vec4(0.4, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0) is just basic color I use

When I prepare data like this:

```
int width, height;
width = 16;
height = 16;
float data[16][16];
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
        data[i][j] = 0.5f;
    }
}

GLuint n_tex_surface;
glGenTextures(1, &n_tex_surface);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, n_tex_surface);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Edit:

INIT

```
vertices[] = {
0, 1, -1, -1, 1, /**/1, 1, 1, -1, 1,/**/ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,/**/ 0, 0, -1, 1, 1};
indices[] = {   
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};

glGenBuffers(1, &n_vertex_buffer_object);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, n_vertex_buffer_object);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &n_index_buffer_object);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, n_index_buffer_object);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &n_vertex_array_object);
glBindVertexArray(n_vertex_array_object);
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, n_vertex_buffer_object);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), p_OffsetInVBO(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), p_OffsetInVBO(2 * sizeof(float)));   

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, n_index_buffer_object);
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

DRAW

```
glBindVertexArray(n_vertex_array_object);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, p_OffsetInVBO(0));
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

My result looks like this:[image: 16]

instead of square with just one color intensity I got this mess. It seems like texture is too small and does not fit square. What size texture should be? And how do I found out?
Am I creating texture the right way?

With dimensions 128x128:
[image: 128]

With 64x64 I got this column, this is what I want, but why isnt it covering whole square?
[image]

This is in OpenGL 3.3 on my computer.

Could you help me?

EDIT:

When I replace my texture creation code with example from Addison Wesley OpenGL Programming Guide it works great, why not my code does not?

```
GLuint n_tex_surface;
GLubyte checkImage[dataheight][datawidth][4];
 int i, j, c;
for (i = 0; i < dataheight; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < datawidth; j++) {
     c = (((i&0x8)==0)^((j&0x8))==0)*255;
     checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
     checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
     checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
     checkImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte) 255;
  }
}

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenTextures(1, &n_tex_surface);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, n_tex_surface);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
               GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
               GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, datawidth, 
            dataheight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
            checkImage);
```

Edit:
vertex shader

```
#version 330
in vec2 v_tex;
in vec3 v_pos;
uniform mat4 t_modelview_projection_matrix;
out vec2 v_texcoord;
void main()
{
gl_Position = t_modelview_projection_matrix * vec4(v_pos, 1.0);
v_texcoord = v_tex;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 330
in vec2 v_texcoord;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D n_box_tex;

void main()
{
frag_color = texture2D(n_box_tex, v_texcoord).r * vec4(0.4, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that draws the trianges incl. the vertices' texture coordinates.

Comment: What does p_OffsetInVbo do?

Comment: #define p_OffsetInVBO(off) ((void*)(off))

Comment: Okay, finally, how do you access the texture coordinates in your shader?

Comment: What happens if you put these two lines into your code? glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46537231/stack_opengl_texture64-nowrap.PNG

Answer (score 7):

You are only allocating enough storage for <sup>1</sup>/<sub>4</sub> of your texture.

You need to use `float data[16][16][4]` and then assign each component of the texture a value of `0.5f`:

```
int width, height;
width = 16;
height = 16;
float data[16][16][4];
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
        data[i][j][0] = 0.5f;
        data[i][j][1] = 0.5f;
        data[i][j][2] = 0.5f;
        data[i][j][3] = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

You are actually lucky that doing what you originally tried did not crash your software. You are/were forcing GL to overrun your allocated storage when it reads the texture image data.

Comment: But I want to create texture where there is only one float value for each pixel. So it wont be RGBA texture. There will be only ..lets say... red channel with float values. How can I do that?

Comment: @Pan.student Well, then use a single channel texture, i.e. `GL_R32F` instead of `GL_RGBA32F` and `GL_RED` instead of `GL_RGBA`. How many channels did you think does a `GL_RGBA32F` texture contain or how OpenGL would be able to determine the internal format you *wanted* by seeing that your provided data is just too short?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, problem was with GL_ constants! 
This works as expected:

```
GLuint n_tex_surface;
GLfloat checkImage[dataheight][datawidth];

for (int i = 0; i < dataheight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < datawidth; j++) {
        float r = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX); = r + 0.01f;
        checkImage[i][j] = (GLfloat) r;
    }
}

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenTextures(1, &n_tex_surface);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, n_tex_surface);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Here we have GL_RED (one channel texture) and it is GL_FLOAT:

```
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, datawidth, dataheight, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, checkImage);
```

Rest of the code and shaders stay the same.

Comment: Wrong answer. `GL_RED` does **not** create a floating point texture. It takes your floating point data and **converts** it into a normalized fixed point format (other than that it's also an unsized format and thus deprecated). What you want is `GL_R32F` (for the internal format, of course, the CPU format is still `GL_RED`).

Comment: So it should be:  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, datawidth, dataheight, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, checkImage); ?

Comment: Exactly. Texture formats like `GL_RGBA` or `GL_RGBA8` are always normalized fixed point regardless of the type of the input data. For integer and floating point textures you need an explicit `F`, `I` or `UI` somewhere in the internal format.

Comment: Accepting the answer that already gave the correct answer to the *original question* and deleting the one that doesn't address the original problem *as stated in the question* would already be sufficient. ;-)